# onPreviewFrame not being called on Nexus 4 phone ... but is on Emulator

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, opticalflow, nexus-4

```
 public boolean openCamera() {
    Log.i(TAG, "openCamera");
    releaseCamera();
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    if (mCamera == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't open camera!");
        return false;
    }

    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {

        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            synchronized (View.this) {
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, mFrame[frameIndex], 0,
                        data.length);
                View.this.notify();
            }
            camera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
            if (frameIndex == 1) {
                bufferIsSet = true;
            }
            frameIndex ^= 1;

        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Above is a method to open the camera. (more code can be found at: https://github.com/sungjkang/OpticalFlow/blob/master/src/com/wais/opticalflow/View.java)

It works okay on my laptop using the emulator, but it doesn't work at all on my Nexus 4. 
After some digging, I was noticing that I was never entering into the onPreviewFrame when I was using my phone, but that method was being called with my emulator.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem.its mostly problem with size, add below code it working for me.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size cs = sizes.get(0);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(cs.width, cs.height);
    // parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.startPreview();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Important](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html): Pass a fully initialized SurfaceHolder to setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder). Without a surface, the camera will be unable to start the preview.